# What's these symbols mean in the function suggestion?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

What are these '*','|', '...', '->'?

Why the words are colored differently, are they have special meanings?

I even have no idea what's the keyword to search in google...
If someone could offer some links explained in detail, that'd be a huge help.

[image]

Comment: '|' is a delimiter between different variant of function arguments supported. [`*values`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) is variadic argument. `...` is [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis), i that particular example it shows you that you can pass *positional* arguments after *keyword*. `->` used to specify return type. More information about typing [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). Also I recommend you to read [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: ```function annotations```.

Comment: `print` is a function that can be called in several ways: for example it can take a variable number of arguments. If you were writing such a function, you would put `*values` in the argument list. VS Code is showing you the full signature of the function. It may take a while before you learn enough Python to write functions with such complicated signatures, but your best route to understanding this notation would start with a close reading of the docs for `print`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The full syntax of `print()`
is:

```py
print(*values, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

And print arguments are:

- *values* - value to the printed. `*` indicates that there may be more than one object;
- *sep* - values are separated by sep. Default value: `' '`;
- *end* - end is printed at last;
- *file* - must be an object with write(string) method. If omitted it, `sys.stdout` will be used which prints objects on the screen;
- *flush* - If `True`, the stream is forcibly flushed. Default value: `False`.

`|` is the same as `or` in Python, and `->` indicates what a function returns. In this case means `print()` returns a value of `None`. Try

```py
return print()
```

or

```py
print(print())
```

Hope I helped

Answer (score 2):

The asterisk (`*`) is Python's syntax for an unknown number of arguments. It is introduced in [section 4.7.4 of the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and described in detail in [section 8.6 of the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions).

The other funny things are type hints, described under [the `typing` module in the library reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).